# See if xml has attribute and value

Tags: javascript, xml

I have some xml that looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
   <body>
      <menu>
         <day name="monday">
            <meal name="BREAKFAST">
               <counter name="Hot Cereal">
                  <dish>
                     <name>Oatmeal</name>
                  </dish>
               </counter>
            </meal>
         </day>
      </menu>
   </body>
</html>
```

I have shortened the xml for this example to make it simpler. Now in javascript I want to check if this xml has value and tags after the meal tag.I am using `sax.js xml` parser and `xmlreader.js` to read the `xml`. Now here is what I have and I am very confused why it is not returning true?

I read the xml and save it as `var res` And then to check whether there are values and tags after meal tag I do this.

```
if (res.html.body.menu.day.at(dayNumber).meal) {
     console.log('IT IS TRUE');
}
```

And it should come true for this xml correct, but it is not what am I missing?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV: please note that inline code spans (`like this`) [should not be used for emphasis](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254990/2074608). Also, please try and improve the post as much as you can when editing. See the [editing guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) for more information. Thanks!

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy sure i will have a look at this, thanks for your valid informations

Answer (score 1):

try with this

```
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("books.xml");
x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("book")[0];

console.log(x.hasAttribute("category"))
```